# Either unformatted I/O is giving absurd values, or I'm reading them incorrectly in R

Tags: r, io, fortran

I have a problem with unformatted data and I don't know where, so I will post my entire workflow.

I'm integrating my own code into an existing climate model, written in fortran, to generate a custom variable from the model output. I have been successful in getting sensible and readable *formatted* output (values up to the thousands), but when I try to write *unformatted* output then the values I get are absurd (on the scale of 1E10).

Would anyone be able to take a look at my process and see where I might be going wrong?

I'm unable to make a functional replication of the entire code used to output the data, however the relevant snippet is;

```
c     write customvar to file [UNFORMATTED]
      open (unit=10,file="~/output_test_u",form="unformatted")
      write (10)customvar
      close(10)

c      write customvar to file [FORMATTED]
c      open (unit=10,file="~/output_test_f")
c      write (10,*)customvar
c      close(10)
```

The model was run twice, once with the FORMATTED code commented out and once with the UNFORMATTED code commented out, although I now realise I could have run it once if I'd used different unit numbers. Either way, different runs should not produce different values.

The files produced are available here;

- [unformatted(9kb)](http://www.filedropper.com/outputtestu)
- [formatted (31kb)](http://www.filedropper.com/outputtestf)

In order to interpret these files, I am using R. The following code is what I used to read each file, and shape them into comparable matrices.

```
##Read in FORMATTED data
formatted <- scan(file="output_test_f",what="numeric")
formatted <- (matrix(formatted,ncol=64,byrow=T))
formatted <- apply(formatted,1:2,as.numeric)

##Read in UNFORMATTED data
to.read <- file("output_test_u","rb")
unformatted <- readBin(to.read,integer(),n=10000)
close(to.read)
unformatted <- unformatted[c(-1,-2050)] #to remove padding
unformatted <- matrix(unformatted,ncol=64,byrow=T) 
unformatted <- apply(unformatted,1:2,as.numeric)
```

In order to check the the general structure of the data between the two files is the same, I checked that zero and non-zero values were in the same position in each matrix (each value represents a grid square, zeros represent where there was sea) using;

```
as.logical(unformatted)-as.logical(formatted)
```

and an array of zeros was returned, indicating that it is the just the values which are different between the two, and not the way I've shaped them.

To see how the values relate to each other, I tried plotting formatted vs unformatted values (note all zero values are removed)

[image: comparison of formatted and unformatted values]

As you can see they have some sort of relationship, so the inflation of the values is not random.

I am completely stumped as to why the unformatted data values are so inflated. Is there an error in the way I'm reading and interpreting the file? Is there some underlying way that fortran writes unformatted data that alters the values?

Comment: Are you sure that it is allowed to simply omit the format specifier in `write`? And, to be sure that the binary file contains what you think it does, have you tried reading the binary file with Fortran and checked its contents?

Comment: If you're referring to the second write statement, for unformatted, then no I am not 100% sure. 
As for your second question, I have not yet but I will try now, as that would help to narrow down the source of the issue to data generation and not interpretation.

Comment: @Stibu: Yes, it is not allowed to have a format specifier for unformatted `WRITE`.

Comment: From tkoenig's answer it seems that using unformatted files with R just leads to a lot of complications. Do you really need unformatted files? Two details regarding your code: Rewriting the `scan` command for the formatted file to `formatted <- scan(file="output_test_f",what=numeric())`, you save the trouble of converting to numeric later. And why do you use `integer()` when reading unformatted, even though you don't have integer data in your file? (Using  `numeric()` does not solve the problem, though...)

Comment: Using unformatted files is not strictly necessary, however I will be running an ensemble of climate simulations, each outputting a new file every month for 100 years or so, so I want to be careful of my file space usage. Also I have been lead to believe that using formatted output considerably slows down the simulation.

Thank you for your R code revision for reading the formatted data, I will implement it now. 
The reason I used `integer()` for unformatted is because using `numeric` gave me half as many values (i.e. 1025 instead of 2050), for a reason completely beyond me.

Comment: What is the type and kind of `customvar` in the Fortran?  Your results suggest to me that you have a data type mismatch (REAL versus INTEGER).

Comment: @IanH It is of REAL type. What do you mean by kind?

Comment: @IanH 
There is a kind of mismatch in that in R I'm using `integer()` while the data being output is real, however I did this because using `numeric()` gives me half as many values, and these values are not any more reasonable than they were before.

If this is the source of the error, then I will ask another question for this specifically.

Comment: Intrinsic types in Fortran are parameterized.  Simplistically, for REAL types the kind indicates whether you are talking single precision, double precision, etc - it may affect the number of bytes to store a value.  For many Fortran compilers the default kind ends up specifying a four byte, "single precision" value.  R's numeric type is an eight byte "double precision" value - hence you see half the values.  Try numeric with a size of four.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from the comments of @Stibu and @IanH, I experimented with the R code and found that the source of error was the incorrect handling of the byte size in R. Explicitly specifying a bite size of 4, i.e

```
unformatted <- readBin(to.read,integer(),size="4",n=10000)
```

allows the data to be perfectly read in.

Answer (score 2):

The usual method that Fortran uses to write unformatted file is:

- A leading record marker, usually four bytes, with the length of the following record
- The actual data
- A trailing record marker, the same number of bytes as the leading record marker, with the same information (used for BACKSPACE)

The usual number of bytes in the record marker is four bytes, but eight bytes have also been sighted (e.g. very old versions of gfortran for 64-bit systems).

If you don't want to deal with these complications, just use stream access. On the Fortran side, open the file with

```
  OPEN(unit=10,file="foo.dat",form="unformatted",access="stream")
```

This will give you a stream-oriented I/O model like C's binary streams.

Otherwise, you would have to look at your compiler's documentation to see how exactly unformatted I/O is implemented, and take care of the record markers from the R side. A word of caution here: Different compilers have different methods of dealing with very long records of more than 2^31 bytes, even if they have four-byte record markers.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did take care of the record markers (they are the values 8192 in the files) by removing them in R, however I will try using stream access now as it will make that step redundant, as well as possibly alleviating my original issue.

Comment: Using `acess="stream"` does indeed prevent having to trim the data file  (I initially thought it wasn't working because it was overwriting the previously made file, preserving the record markers). As expected, it made no change to the values themselves.